# referencing nested \items

Tags: cross-referencing, enumitem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    Show that
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
      \item
      \label{1a}
      2 = 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
From \cref{1a}, we know that 2 = 2.
\end{document}
```

The reference that only says item (a) but I want the reference to say item 1 (a).  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you think of `\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*),ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*)]`?

Comment: @moewe that worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the way the references are displayed you can modify the key `ref=`.
You can access the counter from the levels above by `enumi`, `enumii` etc.

So just add `ref=\arabic{enumi} (\alph*)` or `ref=\theenumi (\alph*)` and it should work as expected (the latter, as @egreg kindly pointed out, *automatically* chooses the representation of the counter as used before, while the former allows to explicitly use `\arabic` numbers).

See also section 3.1 of the [enumitem documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Show that
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*), ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*)]
      \item \label{1a} 2 = 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
From \cref{1a}, we know that 2 = 2.
\end{document}
```